# Entity Framework LINQ statement always translated into WHERE 0 = 1

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

So I have a method with two parameters that I use as filter to get a list of results from a SQL Server database, using EF Core.
Before querying the database I verify that the parameters are not null. If one is null, I query using only the other and vice versa. If both are non nulls I use both of them for my query.

Here is the code :

```
        // At least one parameter must be non null
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(param1) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(param2))
            return;

        // 1) If param1 is null, use the param2 as filter
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(param1))
        {
            list = _context.Foos.AsNoTracking().Where(x => x.Param2 == param2).ToList();
        }
        // 2) If param2 is null, use param1 as filter
        else if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(param2))
        {
            list = _context.Foos.AsNoTracking().Where(x => x.Param1 == param1).ToList();
        }
        // 3) Use both parameters
        else
        {
            list = _context.Foos.AsNoTracking().Where(x => x.Param2== param2 && x.Param1 == param1).ToList();
        }
```

For the first if statement (1) where I query with param2 as filter, the query is always translated into WHERE 0 = 1.
The else if statement (2) works correctly.

Note that is I swap the order (querying with param1 as filter in the first if statement, and param2 in else if), now this is the query with param1 which gets translated into WHERE 0 = 1. So it seems to have nothing to do with the parameter in itself, but with the order in which I proceed.

Any clue on what is happening and how I can resolve this issue?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does it behave incorrectly too if you remove AsNoTracking?

Comment: Instead of using else simply return.  Your code isn't covering all conditions.  This is a great case of spaghetti code.

Comment: @WiktorZychla Yes same result

Comment: @jdweng Yeah I agree with you about the spaghetti aspect of it, but which conditions am I not covering? And I need the else to query using both parameters

Comment: @jdweng [Kevlin Henney disagrees with you](https://youtu.be/mrY6xrWp3Gs?t=2450), and the OP has covered all conditions, but OP, if you are going to use `else` to provide structure, best to use it consistently, which would mean adding an `else` before the `if` in condition (1).

Comment: Is the last ELSE for first IF or for the "ELSE IF"?  Adding return you do not need the ELSE .

Comment: @jdweng I need the else because I can't return the result yet (I'm doing some modifications on my list before returning it). But this is not the point. The fact is that no matter how I arrange my if and else statement, the first if always translate to Where 0 = 1 and I can't figure out why

Comment: The optimizing compiler is removing the unnecessary code because your if/else is not doing what you think it is doing.  It is like logic reduction using Karnaugh Maps.  Unnecessary cases are removed.

Comment: @jdweng Which block do you think is being removed, and how would OP be seeing entity framework's translation of the query to SQL if the block was being removed by the compiler?

Comment: @Champy: could you also show how's your model defined (the `Param1` and `Param2`)

Comment: You will likely need to post the complete code or a reproducible example. Often when attempting to simplify an example you omit a key detail that actually results in the issue you are seeing.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that in the complete code you get a condition like `where someRquiredProperty == null`. EF-core typically turns that into a `WHERE 0 = 1` clause.

Answer (score 0):

Where 0 = 1 indicates there is a optimization taking place in which the code has decided it can never be true hence 1=0. Without seeing the rest of the code it is not possible to say what is going one. However you can simplify this code which might shed some light.

If we setup an IQueryable we can add the filters independently. If there is a value for  param1 then add param1 etc. If both values are present you get both filters. This also makes adding filters other parameters easier

Note the sql is only generated and executed when you call the .ToList() method.

```
// At least one parameter must be non null
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(param1) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(param2))
    return;
    
// Setup IQueryable interface .
IQueryable<Foos> query = _context.Foos();
// param1 has value
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(param1))
{
    query = query.Where(x => x.param1 == param1)
}
// param2 has value
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(param2))
{
    query = query.Where(x => x.param2 == param2)
}
// Run the query.
list = query.AsNoTracking().ToList();
```

Comment: `else if` must be `if`, otherwise it'll never use both parameters.

Comment: Fixed thanks for pointing that out.